# Burning fuel in space while accelerating and deaccelerating

Tags: acceleration, rocket-science, space-travel

Is it true that for acceleration in space we need not the same quantity of the fuel than during the deacceleration stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally true because during the acceleration phase fuel that will later be burned is accelerated along with the ship, whereas upon deceleration the overall mass of the ship will be smaller, requiring less fuel to slow it.

Comment: I felt that there was something about Real Life :)